# Google cloud sdk not working when python points python3

Tags: python, linux, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

I am currently trying to install google cloud sdk on my macbook. I am using scikit-learn and anaconda for machine learning so on my laptop python points to python3.5. However google cloud sdk requires python 2.7 for installation, and that's why I am facing the problem of not be able to install it.

when I ran the install.sh file the error occurred and I have no clue how to deal with it:

```
Adam | ~ $ git/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/Git/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 364, in __getattr__
    return cls._member_map_[name]
KeyError: '_convert'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/git/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/install.py", line 8, in <module>
    import bootstrapping
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/Git/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
    import setup
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/Git/google-cloud-sdk/bin/bootstrapping/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
    from googlecloudsdk.core.util import platforms
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/Git/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/platforms.py", line 18, in <module>
    import platform
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/platform.py", line 117, in <module>
    import sys, os, re, subprocess
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 364, in <module>
    import signal
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/anaconda/lib/python3.5/signal.py", line 8, in <module>
    _IntEnum._convert(
  File "/Users/AdamLiu/Git/google-cloud-sdk/lib/third_party/enum/__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: _convert
```

Super thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable to the location of your Python 2.x executable before running [install.sh](https://github.com/drincruz/google-cloud-sdk/blob/master/install.sh).

Or make sure that you have python2 in your path so that `which python2` can find it.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. But I still don't quite understand how to do it. Is it ok for you to explain it more specifically?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem: [Not working when python points python3](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-sdk/issues/detail?id=355), does it mean I need to create another file named gcloud.workaround and paste the code in it and execute gcloud again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have Python 2.x installed? If not, install it. If it installs as /usr/bin/python2 (or python2 elsewhere on your PATH) then you don't need to do anything else because the install.sh script (read it, it's pretty simple) does a 'which python2' and will find it. Otherwise set the environment variable CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to point at the python 2.x executable via export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=<location-of-python2>.

Comment: Also worth noting that the bundled install doesn't set CLOUDSDK_PYTHON, so if you were to change your path at some point in the future, the sdk will break unless you've set this.